# Java - Sending byte array of MP3 file over TCP port and recieving

Tags: java, tcp, byte, mp3, port

ok so im working on a program with a regular audio player gui but it has the option to take the song currently playing and convert it to a byte[] and send it to a client, where it will then be converted back into a mp3 file and played. not quite streaming but sorta live FTP. however, i can not seem to send the packets, and the reciever creates a blank mp3 file with size 0kb. nothing is being written, and idk why this happening. help pls.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import javazoom.jl.player.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Send {

public String address;
public int port;
public byte[] b;

public Send(String a, int p)
{
    a = address;
    p = port;


    try
    {
        System.out.println("Server started");
        System.out.println(b.length);

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2345);
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Waiting for client to connect...");
        if(socket.isConnected())
        {
            System.out.println("Client connected");
        }

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); 
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
        if(b.length > 1)
        {
            dos.write(b);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }



    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

}

and this is the reciever class, there is a whole gui that goes along with this but i wont add that junk unless you think it would help.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import javazoom.jl.player.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;


public class Recieve {

String host = "localhost";
int port = 2345;
byte[] inFile;
public File file;
public static Socket socket;

public Recieve()
{
    System.out.println("Waiting to connect to server..");

    try
    {   

        socket = new Socket(host,port);

        if(socket.isConnected())
        {
            System.out.println("Connected to server on "+host+": "+port);
        }

        file = new File("H:\\Song.mp3");
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        int bytesRead = is.read(inFile, 0, inFile.length);
        bos.write(inFile, 0, bytesRead);
        bos.close();



        FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

        fop.write(inFile);
        fop.flush();
        fop.close();


        Playmusic play = new Playmusic(file);
        Thread one = new Thread(play);
        one.start();    

        if(file.length() < 2)
        {
            file.delete();
        }


    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("ERROR ON STREAM "+e.getMessage());}



}
```

}

Comment: DO NOT REGARD THAT THE FILE PATHS ARE DIFFERENT THAT WAS DUE TO SWITCHING COMPUTERS. I ALREADY SWITCHED THAT

Comment: The sender uses a `DataOutputStream` to send a byte array. But the receiver only uses a plain `InputStream`. This doesn't match. You should use either a `DataOutputStream`/`DataInputStream` pair or plain `OutputStream`/`InputStream`.